# install4j: What is the best way, to start my application over a link?

Tags: java, jar, install4j

I have a Java application. It is only a JAR file with some additional libs. Under Windows it's enough to make a doubleclick on it, if there are no problems with the installed JRE.

Now I want to make an installer with install4j. I am not able to use java.exe or javaw.exe for a simple link. If I do that, no link is created while the installation. At hits time I use directly the JAR file, but I am sure this will not work on each computer.

I searched for solutions on the internet, but I didn't find the answer I want.

Should I create a Launcher over install4j (EXE file), or should I use a batch file, or is there a better way? I think the best way would be a simple link with 'javaw.exe -jar MyApp.jar'?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most robust approach is to create a launcher. This way, you let install4j deal with finding a JRE, generating platform-specific launch shortcuts, etc. The install4j 'Launcher' wizard is quite intuitive so you should be able to whip up a solution within an hour or two.

[image: install4j launcher wizard]

Alternatively, if you just want to script a shortcut to 'javaw.exe -jar MyApp.jar', there is little value in adding the install4j dependency.